# Want to take a regular backups of files to my google drive account in php

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a file which is updated regularly on server and i want to take backup of this file every day on my Google drive account using  php crone job. I don't want any user auth, is there any way in which i just simply pass my drive username and password along with file and it is uploaded to my drive account.So whenever i access my drive account i found that file there.
Or if is it possible to upload file in Google drive service account and share that particular file with my drive account.

Please help with code.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i got the answer for my question from google drive documentation...it is possible to share file uploaded from service account to any of the google drive account. just we have to provide permissions for that particular file for the drive account in which we have to view that file.... my code is given below:

```
<?php
require_once "google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php";
require_once "google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php";
require_once "google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php";
session_start();

function buildService() {

$DRIVE_SCOPE = array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube', 'https://gdata.youtube.com/action/GetUploadToken', 'https://gdata.youtube.com');
$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'SOMETHING@developer.gserviceaccount.com';

if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'localhost')
$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = 'YOUR_CERTIFICATE-privatekey.p12';
else
$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'YOUR_CERTIFICATE-privatekey.p12';

  $key = file_get_contents($SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH);
  $auth = new Google_AssertionCredentials(
      $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
      $DRIVE_SCOPE,
      $key);

  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName("You Tube API");
  $client->setUseObjects(true);
  $client->setAssertionCredentials($auth);
  $client::$auth->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
  $json = $client->getAccessToken();
  $accessToken = json_decode($json)->access_token;

  return new Google_DriveService($client);
}
function insertFile($service, $title, $description, $parentId, $mimeType, $filename) {

  $file = new Google_DriveFile();
  $file->setTitle($title);
  $file->setDescription($description);
  $file->setMimeType($mimeType);

  try {
    $data = file_get_contents($filename);

    $createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
      'data' => $data,
      'mimeType' => $mimeType,
    ));

    // Uncomment the following line to print the File ID
     //print 'File ID: %s'.$createdFile->getId();
     //print 'Parent ID<pre>'.print_r($createdFile->getParents())."</pre>";

    $fileId = $createdFile->getId();
    $file = $service->files->get($fileId);

    $newPermission = new Google_Permission();
    $newPermission->setValue('DRIVE_ACCOUNT_TO_SHARE@gmail.com');
    $newPermission->setType('user');
    $newPermission->setRole('reader');
    try {
      return $service->permissions->insert($createdFile->getId(), $newPermission);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }


    return $createdFile;
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
}


$service = buildService();

$createdFile=insertFile($service, 'Testing', 'Testing for file upload', 'Parent_Id_', 'application/pdf', 'test.pdf');
echo "<pre>".print_r($createdFile)."</pre>";
?>
```